# ConstraintLayout Bumping TextView Off Screen

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have an XML file with an ImageView and a TextView. Everytime that the TextView is populated, the text goes off of the screen. I looked at other people who have had the same problem and the common solution seems to be to set the Textview's width to 0dp. This hasn't worked for me. Wondering if anyone knows why?

Here is my constraintLayout XML file:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/weather_icon"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/weather_data"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/weather_data"
    android:text="EXAMPLE"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/weather_icon"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Here is what it looks like, text is clearly getting cut off:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution of your problem just use it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/weather_icon"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/weather_data"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/weather_data"
        android:text="EXAMPLE "
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/weather_icon"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Please do not use `match_parent` for widgets inside Constraint Layout, as well as don’t use `left/right` instead use `start/end` for all instances. Also your layout is incomplete, you’re not telling the image view where to vertically pin, so by _default_ it’s staying at the top/left corner. The textView should also be vertically pinned to something.

Comment: Thanks @MartinMarconcini  for reminder, Actually i just edited Mark,s layout.

Comment: No problem! I just like to clarify these when I see them because users then copy-paste without knowing and there are _other_ problems that they are not aware of. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should set the width of your `TextView` to `match_constraint` which, in the XML, will be `0dp`.

And I see you're using both left/right and start/end notations. Stick to only one of them.

I encourage you to use the start/end notation because there might be devices using your app that their language is one that reads from right to left, i.e.: Arabic, so using the start/end you don't have to worry about these devices.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Sandeep and Martin. I combined their suggestions and this works well in the layout:

```
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/weather_icon"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/weather_data"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrapcontent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/weather_data"
    android:text="EXAMPLE"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/weather_icon"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: `android:layout_height=“wrapcontent` should be `android:layout_height=“wrap_content` ;)